# What does a combo deck based around Thran Lens look like?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I like building casual decks based around obscure rares. This one has been sitting in my collection forever, and I've never used it. I'm completely stumped.

[Thran Lens](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thran%20Lens) is a two mana artifact that reads

> All permanents are colorless.

Other than making Black creatures vulnerable to [Dark Banishing](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dark%20Banishing) and the like, what is this card good for? My ideal deck would use the Lens as part of a winning, or at least very annoying combo. I'm not worried about how feasible the combo is to execute - [Rube Goldberg machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) based on many cards are welcome.

There is one important extra caveat. My collection is strictly old-school. I can only use cards from [Scourge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scourge_%28Magic:_The_Gathering%29) or earlier, since those are the only cards I possess (or am willing to buy). On the plus side, I do have most of them...

Comment: That is a fantastic card for beating circles of protection.

Comment: Stephen Colbert would not notice any changes with this card.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two good choices:

- [Invoke Prejudice](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Invoke%20Prejudice) - Affects all opponents in multiplayer.
- **Intimidate** (or Fear) - [Shadowmage Infiltrator](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shadowmage%20Infiltrator) is probably the best Fear creature.

Comment: To add to this: [Avatar of Woe](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=24621) is a great addition to any fear deck.